# Why SignalR hub doesn't update a new function added?

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio, signalr

I am working on a SignalR and C# project. I already have a hub and it's working fine.

But some days ago, I wrote a new function in the hub to use in one of the screens in the system and run the code. To my surprise, it didn't work. So I tried debugging the project, but nothing.

Then I use the console.log command in jQuery to see if there is some error there. So, I was astonished when I saw that the function that I wrote in the hub (in C#) isn't appearing. I don´t know why is this happening.

I tried to change the name of the function, wrote a new function in my code, compile again and much more, but I can´t find the reason why only the new functions isn't appearing in the object. As I said before, the other functions are detected and worked fine, only if I add a new function in the hub is not appearing.

Can you help me please? Here is the code which is working in the hub:

```
public async Task notificacionPedido6(string idPedido, string idDetalle, string accion, string bomba, string mensaje)
{
    DataTable dt = cnx.QuerySender("CALL mensajeNotificacion('" + accion + "');");
    cnx.Conexion.Close();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString() == "Tecnologías de la Información")
        {
            await Clients.Group("Administrador").Message(idPedido + " " + idDetalle + " " + accion + " " + bomba + " " + mensaje);
        }
        else
        {
            await Clients.Group(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString()).Message(idPedido + " " + idDetalle + " " + accion + " " + bomba + " " + mensaje);
        }
    }
}
```

And now, the code which wasn't detected:

```
public async Task ocpendiente(string orden, string accion, string mensaje)
{
    DataTable dt = cnx.QuerySender("CALL mensajeNotificacion('" + accion + "');");
    cnx.Conexion.Close();

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString() == "Tecnologías de la Información")
        {
            await Clients.Group("Administrador").Message(orden + " " + accion + " " + mensaje);
        }
        else
        {
            await Clients.Group(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString()).Message(orden + " " + accion + " " + mensaje);
        }
    }
}
```

If you pay attention, it's too similar. I don't know why it isn't showing up. Please help me.

Thank you so much for your help, have a nice weekend!

I almost forget to tell you: I am using #, Visual Studio 2017 and SignalR 2.4.3

[image]

Comment: I don't see any issues with the steps you provided. You can try clearing the browser cache or trying to access the application in incognito mode first. Also, have you confirmed that your SignalR hub connection is established?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I try all you suggested me, but it's not working. But I check something new: if I do any change in the hub class (add, delete and change functions), it's not reflecting  when I am running the project. Is there a way that the project is taking the last compilation? I already recompiled everyting, but it looks like is running always the same version.